# How do I properly add multiple one-to-one relationships on two tables using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a `Lighthead` class that has two one-to-one relationships with the `Lens` class. When I map the classes as they are set up below I receive the following error.

> The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_Id' already exists on table 'dbo.Lens'.

How do I fix this?

here is my mapping

```
public class LensMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Lens>
{
    public LensMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Lens");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.LightHead)
            .WithOptional(t => t.Lens);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.LightHead1)
            .WithOptional(t => t.Lens1);
    }
}
```

Here is my `lens` class

```
public class Lens
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual LightHead LightHead { get; set; }
    public virtual LightHead LightHead1 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `lighthead` class

```
public class LightHead
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Lens Lens { get; set; }
    public virtual Lens Lens1 { get; set; }
}
```

Note I am using Entity Framework 6 and C#

also I have tried to do this with one LightHead in the Lens class it returns the following error

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'WebApplication2.Models.LightHead_Lens' was not loaded because the type 'WebApplication2.Models.Lens' is not available.

Comment: Your `Lens` class should only have one `LightHead` property.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have it contain an `ICollection<LightHead>` or `IEnumerable<LightHead>`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Entity Framework [table splitting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.8) feature to map two entities to single table.

This also lets you query part of your table columns as single entity in order to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a foreing key here.

```
    // Relationships
    this.HasRequired(t => t.LightHead)
        .WithOptional(t => t.Lens)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.LightHeadId)
    this.HasRequired(t => t.LightHead1)
        .WithOptional(t => t.Lens1);
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.LightHead1Id)
```

...

```
public class Lens
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LightHeadId {get;set;}
    public int LightHead1Id {get;set;}

    public virtual LightHead LightHead { get; set; }
    public virtual LightHead LightHead1 { get; set; }
}

public class LightHead
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Lens Lens { get; set; }
    public virtual Lens Lens1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: adding the foreign Key made the relationships all one to many in the database

Answer (score 0):

So Your mapping should be as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LightHead>.HasOptional(x=> x.Lens).WithRequired(a=> a.LightHead);
modelBuilder.Entity<LightHead>.HasOptional(x=> x.Lens1).WithRequired(a => a.LightHead1);
modelBuilder.Entity<Lens>().Property(x=> x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

You need to set databaseGeneratedOption to None becuase Id of Lens will be same as Id of LightHead as in one to one relationship you can't have primary keys in secondary tables.

Secondary entity is treated as extension of primary entity.

Comment: This is essentially what I have and it generates the error I stated in my question.

Comment: One more logical problem here i.e. two property referring to same table and I believe because of that it is not possible what you want to do. The thing is when you have both properties loaded both will have same Id as LensHead,  and to store same primary key more than once in same table is not possible. Hence you getting this error.

Comment: I know you can create more then one, one to zero relationship in SQL although I do not know if EF supports this situation